# Pylint import and ModuleNotFound error - Unable to import modules like scrapy and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am writing a spider to crawl a website but when I run `scrapy crawl scraper_bot_name` I receive a `ModuleNotFound` error : `No module named scrapy.spider` where `scrapy.spider` is the first import statement.

Furthermore, I checked in VSCode if I could find something else, I saw this issue with all the `from … import …`  statements, the error reads - `Unable to import ‘scrapy.spider’pylint(import-error)`

**I tried finding a solution and the most common fix mentioned is checking the project directory structure. Specifically, it is mentioned to check whether any files in the project have been named `scrapy.py` . This is not the case for my project, also I am facing the issue with `sqlalchemy` as well so I don’t think that’s the issue.**

Here’s the directory structure -

- scrape_workspace

  - my_scraper

    - scraper_app

      - **init**.py
      - items.py
      - models.py
      - settings.py
      - pipelines.py
      - spiders

        - **init**.py
        - angellist_spider.py
    - scrapy.cfg
    - Test(virtual env - also have another virtual env in a directory parallel to scrape_workspace)

Here’s the traceback -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File “/Users/arif/newcoderProjects/scrape/ScrapProj/bin/scrapy”, line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File “/Users/arif/newcoderProjects/scrape/ScrapProj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py”, line 142, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File “/Users/arif/newcoderProjects/scrape/ScrapProj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py”, line 280, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File “/Users/arif/newcoderProjects/scrape/ScrapProj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py”, line 152, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = self._get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "/Users/arif/newcoderProjects/scrape/ScrapProj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 146, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "/Users/arif/newcoderProjects/scrape/ScrapProj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 68, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
  File "/Users/arif/newcoderProjects/scrape/ScrapProj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 24, in __init__
    self._load_all_spiders()
  File "/Users/arif/newcoderProjects/scrape/ScrapProj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 51, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/Users/arif/newcoderProjects/scrape/ScrapProj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py”, line 77, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File “/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py”, line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File “<frozen importlib._bootstrap>”, line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/arif/newcoderProjects/scrape_workspace/my_scraper/scraper_app/spiders/angellist_spider.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy.spider'
```

Comment: from scrapy.Spider import BaseSpider not scrapy.spider is what you probably want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're not importing BaseSpider properly.

```
from scrapy.Spider import BaseSpider
```

Comment: yes found the problem, i was referring to old docs of scrapy and thus the error.